# Is it possible to write a program with thousand or fewer characters that can generate every possible 128-kilobyte file

Tags: computation-theory

I found this question in a German math textbook [Konkrete Mathematik (nicht nur)
für Informatiker].

I know that this is not possible but I can not come up with a convincing argument. I think there are sequences of Bytes that can not be computed thus you need at least as many Bytes as you want to write to the file.

I hope somebody can provide a more accurate and convincing argument. Thanks.

I tried to find answers in the internet with no success. I hope to get a computation theoretical kind of answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible -- as a demonstration, below is a 615-byte C program that will generate every possible file that is `numBytes` bytes long (where `numBytes` is a constant that you can set on line 7).  It prints the contents of each possible file to stdout as a row of hexadecimal byte-values.

Note that I set `numBytes` to 3 so that when you run the program you can see it run to completion in a reasonable amount of time.  You can change `numBytes` to 128KB (128*1024) if you want, but then it will take a long time for the program to complete :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   const int numBytes = 3; //128*1024;

   unsigned char * buf = (unsigned char *) malloc(numBytes);
   memset(buf, 0, numBytes);

   int keepGoing = 1;
   while(keepGoing)
   {  
      for (int i=0; i<numBytes; i++) printf("%02x ", buf[i]);
      printf("\n");
      
      unsigned char * op = buf+(numBytes-1);
      unsigned char * p  = op;
      while(*p == 0xFF)
      {  
         (*(--p))++;
         if ((p == buf)&&(*p == 0x00)) {keepGoing = 0; break;}
      }
      (*op)++;
   }
   free(buf);

   printf("done!\n");
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, I was sure it is not possible, thanks Jeremy